# Control servo motor using a web server

Tags: python, web-server, php, servo

So I'm trying to get this to work. I have a .py file that turns the servo, and it works, but I'm trying to run it through a browser.

So I installed apache and php, and I made .php file which, when opened in a browser, runs commands in the terminal:

```
<?php
system("gpio -g mode 4 out");
system("gpio -g write 4 1");
?>
```

It successfully turns on the led. But I tried making a .php file that would run the .py file which spins the servo:

```
<?php
system("python /home/pi/Desktop/python/servo.py");
?>
```

I also tried adding sudo in there but didn't get any results.
If anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this is a permissions problem.

Try adding `www-data` to the `gpio` group.  This may be enough to allow it to manipulate the GPIO.  You will probably have to restart the web server for the permission change to take effect.

`sudo adduser www-data gpio`

I have not considered the security implications of giving `www-data` GPIO access.

---

An alternative is to use (my) pigpio daemon.

On the Pi make sure the pigpio daemon is running.

`sudo pigpiod` # as a one off command

or

`systemctl enable pigpiod` # to start daemon at boot

You can then use the [pigpio Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module or the [pigs command](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) to control the servos.

For a Python example see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_servo_demo_py

Comment: In that case wouldn't this command also fail?: system("gpio -g mode 4 out");

Comment: @JohnHawthorne The wiringPi gpio utility is set uid root.  `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 37068 Oct 31 13:51 /usr/bin/gpio`

Comment: I've tried adding a line to the sudoers file, like people suggested, but it corrupted it and I had to reinstall my system.

Comment: And that should not be the problem, because the first code works, the python command does not.

Comment: @SteroidCookies Why didn't you do what you were asked to do?  If you didn't understand what was suggested you should have asked for clarification.  I explained why the `gpio` command would work.

Comment: So i just run sudo adduser www-data gpio in the terminal?

Comment: @joan Im using RPi3b if it helps

Comment: Yes, run the command in a terminal.

Comment: @joan its still not working, the script works, but not through the php. Is there any other way for me to control the servo through a webserver, besides python, because its crucial. Thank you.

Comment: @SteroidCookies Have added a pigpio alternative.

Comment: @joan sorry but I don't really understand the question.